# How to create a .txt file in Python? (Pycharm)

Tags: python, io, pycharm

In a previous post, I asked how to create a new file to be written in if it didn't already exist. However, I've just tried this in PyCharm, and it's not working. I don't see any sign of the file LOOKHERE.txt

```
my_list = [i**2 for i in range(1,11)]

openfile = open('LOOKHERE.txt', 'w')
for item in my_list:
    openfile.write(str(item) + "\n")
openfile.close()
```

What am I doing wrong? Could it have anything to do with PyCharm's use of projects?

Comment: give your file a path or look into the directory from where this this script was executed

Comment: @Rash Yeah, i looked into the same file path as my .py file was saved, but it's not there. Does this mean every time I want to create a new file, I have to specify a path? From other posts, I was told Python would do it automatically.

Comment: Its a good practice to always specify a path. However like others have said, if u dont, then the default is the current directory. If you don't see it, then verify by giving path that your program is correct.

Comment: Reiterating what @Rash said, the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says: *"Explicit is better than implicit"*.

Comment: You may also have changed your system path because of which you might be thinking that your program runs from folder a, but actually is running from folder b. Also I would advice you to check the folder where the python is installed - your file may be there. There are other things to check such as print the path of current directory before you create the file. Also i dont know about pycharm, but in eclipse if I dont refresh my project, my folder structure does not get updated meaning that your file may be created, its just a matter of refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text file is created in the pycharm project folder, like you suggested.
If you want it to go elsewhere, like your desktop for instance, do this:

```
f = open('path_to_desktop/file.txt', 'w')
```

Note: I just tested this on my own system. I was able to get the project path by right-clicking the folder in the project window(on the right), and clicking 'copy path' from the menu that pops up.

EDIT: I assume since you accepted my answer, that this worked out for you eventually(though please, any other questions, do comment). Just wanted to add, as @ThanePlummer mentioned, that it's generally better practice to use the with statement when opening files. One reason being that your files get auto-closed for you! Google it up ;)

Answer (score 0):

First you should explicitly specify the path. Do this using the `r` specifier and the `join` command so that it is platform independent. It's best to use the `with` keyword when operating on files.

```
import os

my_path = r'my/longpath/here' # forward slash works on all systems

my_list = [i**2 for i in range(1,11)]

with open(os.path.join(my_path, 'subdir', 'LOOKHERE.txt'), 'w') as fh:
    for item in my_list:
        openfile.write(str(item) + "\n")
```

Comment: Better yet use the builtin os.path module to manipulate paths.  (particularly join).

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps you meant this comment for the other post? `os.path.join()` is utilized in this solution.

Comment: I meant do this:  os.path.join("my", "long", "path", "goes", "here") as your path isn't portable as it stands (or alternatively "my/long/path/goes/here" will work everywhere).   It's no big deal.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog Edited as per your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm you can specify working directory to point the location where program should be executed.
Open `Edit Configuration` by pressing `Shift+Alt+F10` and then `0` or with Navigation Bar. Then in `Working directory` select project's path.